# Trying to change cell padding using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a javascript function that will effectively pull down the menu and make it bigger using the css padding attribute.

Here is the original html(The part I want is in navbar.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lux</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pageFunctions.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="setUpSlideShow(); openPage()">
    <?php include 'navbar.php' ?>
    <div class="content">
            <div id="slideshow">
                <div id="slides">
                    <div class="slide"><a href="under_construction.php"><img src="images/tshirt.jpg" class="mainImage" /></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="under_construction.php"><img src="images/MOON.jpg" class="mainImage" /></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="under_construction.php"><img src="images/MOON2.jpg" class="mainImage" /></a></div>
                </div>
                <div id="slides-controls">
                    <a href="#"></a>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then navbar.php is as follows:

```
<div id="headbar">
        <div class="headholder">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <a href="/lux/"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="clothing.php"><li>Clothing</li></a>
                <a href="about.php"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="contact.php"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

The css for headbar is:

```
#headbar {
width: 100%;
background-color: #999999;
padding: 35px 0 0 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

And lastly the code for the javascript is:

```
function openPage() {
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
        document.getElementById('headbar').style.paddingTop+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, looks good. But, can you use jQuery?

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: @JamesMontagne its just not working, the files are uploaded but it is just not executing so I thought it might have been something with my code

Comment: it was not working because the padding is measured in pixels so you'd have to write something like this:
document.getElementById('headbar').style.paddingTop='100px';
the only way i can think to make a string like this changeable is to take the substring of the number, add to the number and then add the px on the end again, is there an easier way without using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

One better option is to try this:

```
function openPage() {
    var i, el = document.getElementById('headbar');
    for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
        el.style.paddingTop = el.style.paddingTop + i;
    }
}
```

Or you can use jQuery's `.animate()` method.

Comment: I would also use the var declaration only once: var i, el = document.getElementById('headbar');  Then refer to your var in the loop: el.style.paddingTop = el.style.paddingTop + 1;